# MySQL finding rows in one table with information from another

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I have two MySQL tables.

First table stores relation between the friend and his picture.

TABLE 1

```
 id  |  pic_id  |  friend_id
----------------------------
 0   |  123     |  84589
 1   |  290     |  11390
 2   |  884     |  84589
```

TABLE 2

Second table stores more information about the pic...

```
id   |  pic_id  |  title   |  color  |  detail
----------------------------------------------
0    |  123     | hello    |  black  |  brush
1    |  124     | world    |   red   |  paint
2    |  884     | sample   |  green  |  star
```

I have my friend_id and need to grab all the pic_id from Table 1 and then use the pic_id to grab the columns from Table 2(title, color, detail)...

How would I do this in MySQL?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply join the two tables.

```
SELECT b.title, b.color, b.detail
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b
        on a.pic_id = b.pic_id
WHERE friend_id = 84589
```